# Rails + Instagram gem: Is there any way to get a specific count of photos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, instagram, photos

I am trying to get 100 newest photos, like

```
client.tag_recent_media("cat", count: 100)
```

but it always return around 40 photos (sometimes 36, sometimes 38 and sometimes 40).
I am working with [this gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem).

Is there any wat to fetch 100 photos or 40 is the limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job:

```
def search_method

  result = []
  next_id=nil
  while result.length < 100
    data = client.tag_recent_media("cat", max_id: next_id) if a.length == 0
    next_id = data.pagination.next_max_id
    result.concat(data)
  end

end
```

Comment: Where do you define `a` here?

Comment: hmm, okay, actually I don't remember now... maybe forget about that if?

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this

```
  client.tag_recent_media(1907035, {count: 60})
```

Unfortunately I think 60 is the maximum amount of photos.

Comment: Can you confirm if that was helpful?

Comment: This works for me, since know I have more than 20 results by default: 33, anyway, for my test, everytime 33 is the max count, for #love for example.